# How to declare my method to receive any kind of list as argument?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static int menu(String texto, ArrayList<String> opciones) {
    for (int i = 0; i < opciones.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ") " + opciones.get(i));
    }

    return solicitarNumero(texto + " [1-"
            + opciones.size() + "]", true, 1, opciones.size());
}
```

I have this method that receives a text (texto) prompting the user to input an option number and an ArrayList with the options.
e.g. {Create entry, remove entry, quit}

solicitarNumero handles the request of the option number and verifies it.

Right now when I'm calling this method using variables of different classes (Franquicia, Gerente, Sistema) I have to go over each ArrayList and create a new one containing that class' toString.

Like so

```
for (Franquicia franquicia : listaFranquicia) {
    listaDatosFranquicia.add(franquicia.toString());
}
```

Then I use the method with the new ArrayList.

```
menu("Ingrese el numero de franquicia "
            + "que desea asignar a este control",
            listaDatosFranquicia) - 1));
```

Is there a way I could simply do

```
menu("Ingrese el numero de franquicia "
            + "que desea asignar a este control",
            listaFranquicia) - 1));
```

Without having to create a new ArrayList?

Comment: `franquicia` is already an ArrayList of `Franquicia`s, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Change the method to

```
public static int menu(String texto, List<?> opciones) {
    for (int i = 0; i < opciones.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ") " + opciones.get(i));
    }

    return solicitarNumero(texto + " [1-"
            + opciones.size() + "]", true, 1, opciones.size());
}
```

which is basically equivalent to:

```
public static int menu(String texto, List<?> opciones) {
    for (int i = 0; i < opciones.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ") " + opciones.get(i).toString());
    }

    return solicitarNumero(texto + " [1-"
            + opciones.size() + "]", true, 1, opciones.size());
}
```

unless one of your options is null (in which case the second one will cause a NullPointerException, whereas the first one will print "null").

`List<?>` means: a list of some unknown type. But since all types extend java.lang.Object, and all you care about is the toString() representation of the objects, you don't really need to know the actual generic type of the list.

Comment: Yeah, good answer, exactly what I thought too, but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Great, that worked!

Instead of changing to List<?> I was trying List<Object>

Answer (score 1):

Not without changing the method `menu`.

`listaFranquicia` is a `List<Franquicia>` and the method expects a `List<String>` so you need to convert each `Franquicia` into a `String` and make a new list with the result, exactly with the code you have.

It's a bit cumbersome but note that with Java 8, it can be written more simply in a single line:

```
List<String> listaDatosFranquicia = listaFranquicia.stream()
                                                   .map(Franquicia::toString)
                                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This would cover the case where, some day in the future, the OP does not want to call `toString` anymore but a more specific method like `getTitle` or something.

Answer (score -2):

I think a much better signature for your `menu` method would be

```
public static int menu(final String texto, final List<?> opciones)
```

This way you can accept any kind of list of objects, and it will rely on how that instance implements `toString()` method.

Also note I changed `ArrayList` to List. It is always better to use the interface instead of the specific implementation when possible.

Comment: That won't allow passing any kind of list. Only List<Object>. And a List<Franquicia> is NOT a List<Object>. Read my answer.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I always forget it about generics in Java.